# How to get the desired data from 3 tables in Athena SQL query?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, inner-join, presto, amazon-athena

Table 1 (`aws_complianceitem`) has no primary key and this sample data:

| status | severity | compliancetype | title | resourceid | region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| compliant | low | security | 2002 patch | i-76765434 | ap-south-2 |
| noncompliant | high | audit | 2002 kb patch | i-76765434 | ap-south-2 |
| compliant | medium | security | 2002 kb patch | i-98765434 | ap-south-1 |

Table 2 (`aws_instanceinformation`) has `ipaddress` and `instanceid` as unique keys, and has this sample data:

| computername | instanceid | ipaddress | status | accountid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SD-SDYH-re22 | i-76765434 | 10.33.23.1 | complianed | 887878787654 |
| noncompliant | i-98765434 | 10.72.33.1 | non-complianed | 098776765478 |

Table 3 (`configinstancestate`) has `ipaddress` and `resourceid` as unique keys and this sample data:

| resourceid | ipaddress | instancestate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| i-76765434 | 10.33.23.1 | running |
| i-98765434 | 10.72.33.1 | stopped |

I need the data with all the instanceid's which are running.

This is the desired result:

| status | instancestate | severity | title | resourceid | region | ipaddress |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| compliant | running | low | 2002 patch | i-76765434 | ap-south-2 | 10.33.23.1 |
| noncompliant | running | high | 2002 kb patch | i-76765434 | ap-south-2 | 10.33.23.1 |
| compliant | stopped | medium | 2002 kb patch | i-98765434 | ap-south-1 | 10.72.33.1 |

tried with the full outer join with below query,

```
SELECT
    t1.status
    , t1.severity
    , t1.title
    , t1.region
    , t1.resourceid
    , t2.ipaddress
    , t2.computername
    , t2.status
    , t3.instancestate
FROM
    aws_complianceitem                      t1
    FULL OUTER JOIN aws_instanceinformation t2
        ON t1.resourceid = t2.instanceid
    FULL OUTER JOIN configinstancestate     t3
        ON t2.ipaddress = t3.resourceid
```

but we filter this result which we get as a part of this query with instancestate=blank, has empty records

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like two inner joins - with the relevant conditions - do what you want:

```
select ac.*, c.*
from aws_complianceitem ac
inner join aws_instanceinformation ai 
    on ai.resourceid = ac.resourceid
inner join configinstancestate c
    on c.resourceid = ac.resourceid and c.ipaddress = ac.ipaddress
```

Comment: Queries of this type are not supported (Service: AmazonAthena; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequestException; Request ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-1exxxxxxxxxx)



getting above error in athena with this query

Comment: @Gandharkhaladkar: I just fixed a typo (trailing `and`). Does it work better now?